# Batch processing on Google Compute Engine in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, batch-processing, google-compute-engine

How do I get started with Compute Engine and setup a Java batch job that; runs continuously with very small intervals (constantly), reads from Google Datastore, processes the data and writes to Google Datastore?

Right now I have a game application running on GAE. When users initiate a game an entity is stored in the Datastore. The game is someway time-based and I wanna be able to frequently and efficiently check the games and make notifications if necessary. At the moment this is done by a task queue that runs for 10 minutes and schedules itselves when it is finish. However I do not feel that this is the correct way to handle this, and will therefore migrate to GCE for better performance and scaling opportunities.

I have read the GCE “get-started-guide”, but this only tells how to connect via SSH and install programs and how to make a very simple website. Where can I find a guide that explains how to create an initial Java project aimed for GCE and using some of Google APIs like Datastore etc. Any advices on how to get started is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at [Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron)?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at it, but I want the job to run all constantly and check for any changes. If I did it with a cron job it would be almost the same as now, where I run a loop for 10 minutes that checks for changes and processes the data, and then shut down, just to start right after by a task in the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud DevRel has started some guides to provide some clarification on this exact topic, like http://cloud.google.com/python, http://cloud.google.com/nodejs, etc, but Java won't be finished for a few months.

If you like fully controlling your infrastructure, you can definitely use GCE, but if I were you, I would stick to App Engine, since it automates a lot of scaling you would have to do manually. GCE provides auto-scaling features, but they are more involved than App Engine. But if you want to see what they look like, the Python GCE section isn't especially specific to Python:

https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine#multiple_instances

If you're finding App Engine limiting, you can look into migrating instead to [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/), which is similar to App Engine but lets you do things like install custom libraries using a Dockerfile.

As far as Task Queues, they are still officially supported, but if you are interested in massive scalability, you can checkout [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) as well and see if it fits your needs.

If your data size is getting large, [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) lets you run real-time streaming or batch jobs that read from Datastore and do some calculations on it. Cloud Dataflow can read from both Datastore and Pub/Sub queues.

If you want to interact with APIs like Pub/Sub or Datastore outside of the context of App Engine, the traditional client library is here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

Although there is a newer project to provide more friendly, easier to use client libraries. They are still in an early state, but you can check them out here:

https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcloud-java

Overall, if your current App Engine and Task Queue solution works, I would stick with it. Based on what you're telling me, the biggest change I would make is instead of your batch job polling every ten minutes, I would have the code that stores the entity in Datastore immediately kick off a Task Queue job or a Pub/Sub message that starts the background processing job.

If you're interested in where the platform is heading, you can check out some of the links here. While you can roll your own solutions on GCE, to me the more interesting parts of the platform our products like Managed VMs, and Cloud Dataflow since they allow you to solve a lot of these problems at a much higher level and save you a lot of headaches of setting up your infrastructure. However, most of these are still in a Beta stage, so they might have a few rough edges for a little bit.

If this doesn't answer your question, comment any more questions and I will try to edit in the answers. And stay tuned for a much better guide to the whole platform for Java.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have just skimmed through Cloud Pub/Sub and Cloud Dataflow and it sounds very promising, as I would rather stick to the built-in auto-scaling. I forgot to mention that the task queue I am using now runs "constantly" because I have a 10 minutes loop where the processing is taking care of, and then it stops and re-schedules the job to be run immediately after again because I want it to be near real-time. I guess this is bad practice? And that is why I will away from it. Can I use Cloud Pub/Sub for tasks that are not always triggered by user events?

Comment: I.e. can I use one of the above services for tasks that are not triggered by a user action, but instead create a "job/solution" that runs constantly and pulls/reads real-time data from the Datastore to check whether there are something to be processed. If there are it will process the tasks and send a push notifications to the users if needed. The push notifications are already in place at GAE. Should I then just trigger that notification queue by http from either Google Pub/Sub and/or Dataflow? Thanks..

Comment: My point was that by running for 10 minutes, then re-scheduling, you are polilng Datastore. What I am recommending is that instead, whenever you write to Datastore, publish a Pub/Sub message with the key of your change. Then you can either use a separate App Engine module or a Dataflow streaming job to do the backgrond processing.  Instead of polling for changes, push the changes when you make them. The Getting Started Python link publishes to Pub/Sub whenever a new book is created and a background module looks up the Books info the Books API as an example.

Comment: Thank you. I will certainly use the push technique on user actions, but the game is somewhat time based, so the system has to check game states at certain times in order to check for inactive etc. Therefore I need a continuous background job to check all running game states. I think I will create a separate module who polls data for those background tasks. Or would it be possible / better to schedule future tasks for each game state, so that they are checked when needed with 1, 2 or 3 days ahead?

Comment: Would the following be a good idea: each time a user makes an action I will schedule a task that checks 1, 2 and 3 days ahead to check if the user has acted since last. If not the user will be game over. But this will schedule a lot of tasks that might be unnecessary when they are executed. So can I either delete tasks? Or maybe create some "do check" entities stored in the datastore and then have a 1 minutes cron job that runs and checks if there are any "do check" entities and then create a separate task for each or just a task that batch processes all necessary "do check" entities at once.

Comment: I have now implemented it in the following: when the user acts a job is scheduled to run 24h after, if the last activity has changed when the job runs, it terminates. Otherwise it sends a reminder notification and schedules another job to run 24 after. When the inactivity limit is exceeded the user is game over. And it is done in a manual scaling module which polls the database in frequent intervals in a 24h task that reschedules all the time.